# Unable to load specific url in wkwebview but loading properly in Safari browser

Tags: swift, wkwebview

Unable to load the following URL in iphone the first time, works only after hitting refresh:

https://www.zerozone.in/demo/?token=VTZBb2W2083kbhJUlhi8nwACAy8EWR0Gv0qRqJ5CWpi%2fJvbZ3EO06uHAmYM%2brrja&baseloannumber=1250%2fMSL%2f4442&customerid=147684&availablelimit=3770&created_thru=1&parent_loanid=222042&loan_charge=100

only on hitting refresh does the website load after significant delay. This website loads perfectly fine in Safari browser

Am i missing something?, please help

```
private func showWebView() {

   let urlString = "https://www.zerozone.in/demo/?token=VTZBb2W2083kbhJUlhi8nwACAy8EWR0Gv0qRqJ5CWpi%2fJvbZ3EO06uHAmYM%2brrja&baseloannumber=1250%2fMSL%2f4442&customerid=147684&availablelimit=3770&created_thru=1&parent_loanid=222042&loan_charge=100"

   if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
       present(SFSafariViewController(url: url), animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

I also tried using WkWebview but to no avail

Comment: Its not loading in browser also (Using Safari)

Comment: it does load in mine. though after a long delay